Is it possible to send the message from the different from number in the WhatsApp API integration?
The goal here is to send the notification to the users of my application, but I want to send notifications from the different numbers depending on the specific app. For example, workout notifications will be sent by a different number, diet notifications will be sent by a different number. It this possible?

I have tried setting up WhatsApp Business and Developer account to test it myself but my account is stuck in verification process
I have also tried going through the documentation, however, I didn't find anything there about it.


You need multiple WhatsApp Business Accounts (WABAs) for each number, with each number verified under its own WABA. Customize your system to route messages through the appropriate WABA based on the notification type. While WABA verification may pose challenges, it reduces the risk of blocking later. Alternatively, consider unofficial APIs that don't require verification, allowing easier management if you have multiple WhatsApp apps on the same phone.

You can setup multiple bots using meta Cloud API:

Setup a "master" server callback to get all messages
Setup bots that you want using token/number

I will show an example using Redis for share queues:
Class for handle with redis:
class CustomWhatsappBot(WhatsappBot):
redis_conn = Redis()

def enqueue_update(self, update):
    # Bot numbers are not always the same
    # So they need to be extracted from the incoming update

    bot_number = update.metadata.display_phone_number

    self.redis_conn.lpush(f"whatsapp:updates:{bot_number}", update.to_json())

def get_update(self):
    # Bot number is consistent here, as we're retrieving updates for the bot

    return self.redis_conn.lpop(f"whatsapp:updates:{self.bot_number}")

Master server (server.py):
message_gateway = CustomWhatsappBot(WHATSAPP_TOKEN, VERIFY_TOKEN, _can_run_empty=True)

# Create Flask app (Gunicorn will use this)
app = message_gateway.create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

Basic structure for bot (botA.py, botB.py etc):
async def main():
bot = CustomWhatsappBot(WHATSAPP_TOKEN, VERIFY_TOKEN, BOT_NUMBER)

"""
Logic to handle incoming messages is omitted here
"""

await bot.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Starting they two together, you can setup many bots you want!
